# Pull access denied for pycharm_helpers, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I am attempting to run the pycharm debugger inside a docker container. This has worked for me in the past, so I know my config is right, but during one of my docker container purges, I must have deleted a container pycharm needs, pycharm_helpers. Unfortunately pycharm can't recover and pull/rebuild the correct images itself, and I can't successfully repull the image manually (yes, I'm logged in to docker registry). Any way to reset this mess, or pull pycharm_helpers? I have tried cache invalidate/restart already

[image]

Comment: I did manage to pull and build pycharm_helpers, but it didn't help. Pycharm apparently needs to be able to pull itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was happening to me because Pycharm was holding onto stale containers, running (remove pycharm containers): **`docker ps -a | grep -i pycharm | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm`**
, then doing **invalidate cache and restart** in pycharm fixed it for me.