# Can't setting Remote interpreter for pycharm

Tags: pycharm

interpreter doesn't show.
I don't know what is the cause.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Getting the following error:

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
failed to run generator3.py for docker- 
compose://[D:\Project\Docker\Web\docker-compose.yml]:django/python, exit code 1, stderr: 
        -----
        Pulling pycharm_helpers (pycharm_helpers:PY-181.5087.37)...
        pull access denied for pycharm_helpers, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
        -----
```

Comment: This happened to me as well, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51776339/2884555